# I get the error "expected ‘;’ before ‘!’ token"

Tags: c, menu

```
int menu () {
    char choice [5];
    int i;
    int c;

    printf("Welcome to your own personal tamaguchi!");

    printf("\n 1.Name your tamaguchi.\n");
    printf("\n 2.Check health and age.\n");
    printf("\n 3.Feed tamaguchi.\n");
    printf("\n 4. Exercise with tamaguchi.\n");
    printf("Let tamaguchi sleep.n");
    printf("\n 5. Close program.\n");

    printf("Choose action: ");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    printf("\n");

     for (i=0; choice[i]! = '\0'; i++){
         if(!isdigit(choice[i]))
            return -1;
    }

    c = atoi(choice);
    return c;
}
```

They say the problem lies where `!` is where `choice[i]!='\0'`.

I have included stdio, string, time and stdlib. 
I don't know what I've done wrong, if you can see the mistake please tell me?

Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: No length check on input....

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it might be a typo, I too voted to close, but also it can be that the OP thinkgs `!` and `=` are separate operators when used as `!=`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
for (i=0; choice[i]! = '\0'; i++){
```

to

```
for (i=0; choice[i] != '\0'; i++){
                    ^
                    |  //notice here
```

The operator here is *not equal to*  `!=`. This is a single operator.

If you write like `! =` [with a space in between], that becomes two separate operators,  Logical NOT and assignment, thereby producing the error.